# How to exclude parameter values from SSRS report

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, reporting-services, parameters

I have an SSRS report we want to deploy as a tool to look up companies in our database using either the primary or secondary phone number. The parameter should able to search both the primary and secondary phone# columns(If it can be done using 2 separate parameters that's fine too).
The problem i'm having is i can't limit or control data users would be able to pull. They run their report using the AD credentials so i'm not sure how to apply security in the report query.
Currently, if i run the report with just a space character, ( I didn't enable "Allow Blank Values") it returns all companies that have either a blank primary or secondary phone number...I tried forcing the phone number parameter to be >= 7 characters, but still didn't work. Tried adding <> ' ' but that didn't work either.

The report is a very simply select statement;

```
select cmp_id, cmp_name, cmp_primaryphone,cmp_secondaryphone,  cmp_billto, cmp_shipper, cmp_consingee, c.cty_name, c.cty_state from company
inner join city c on company.cmp_city=c.cty_code
where cmp_active='Y' and cmp_primaryphone=@PhoneNumber
or cmp_secondaryphone=@PhoneNumber
and len(cmp_primaryphone)>=7
and len(cmp_secondaryphone)>=7
```

Tried a few variations of the above for the phone number clauses, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The @PhoneNumber would have to have an exact match of the primary or secondary phone numbers to return a Company. SQL Server counts '' the same as a space - ' ' which may be why you're getting all the records when you use a space.

There is an issue with your OR statement in the WHERE clause - the OR separates the entire WHERE clause to be one OR the other.

```
select cmp_id, cmp_name, cmp_primaryphone,cmp_secondaryphone,  cmp_billto, cmp_shipper, cmp_consingee, c.cty_name, c.cty_state from company
inner join city c on company.cmp_city=c.cty_code
where cmp_active='Y' and 
    ((cmp_primaryphone=@PhoneNumber and len(cmp_primaryphone)>=7)
    OR (cmp_secondaryphone=@PhoneNumber and len(cmp_secondaryphone)>=7) )
```

Your query was either

```
where cmp_active='Y' and cmp_primaryphone=@PhoneNumber
```

**OR**

```
where cmp_secondaryphone=@PhoneNumber
and len(cmp_primaryphone)>=7
and len(cmp_primaryphone)>=7
```

My guess is your records were all blank primary phone numbers where they are **Active**.

Comment: I relaized i had a small typo in my WHERE clause ( Had cmp_primaryphone listed twice...). I figured out that i can't really have the parameter search 2 different columns, so i'm ok with having 2 different parameters. I just need to be able to exclude being able to search a space character. I will try Molley's suggestion below and report back. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

What if you try changing your WHERE clause to the following?

```
WHERE cmp_active='Y' 
   AND ((RTrim(LTrim(@PhoneNumber)) IS NOT NULL) AND ((cmp_primaryphone=@PhoneNumber)
or (cmp_secondaryphone=@PhoneNumber)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a suggestion on another forum and the issue became kind of obvious; I didn't separate my AND OR arguemnts in the where clause; I simply added brackets around the arguments in the WHERE clause and it fixed my issue.
I also added an error message to be displayed if the parameter is less than 7 characters. Here's what it looks like now:

```
select cmp_id, cmp_name, cmp_primaryphone,cmp_secondaryphone,  
cmp_billto, cmp_shipper, cmp_consingee, c.cty_name, c.cty_state 
from company
join city c on company.cmp_city=c.cty_code
where cmp_active='Y' 
and (cmp_primaryphone=@PhoneNumber and LEN(cmp_primaryphone)>=7) 
or (cmp_secondaryphone=@PhoneNumber and LEN(cmp_secondaryphone)>=7)

IF(LEN(@PhoneNumber)<7)
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('#######YOU HAVE NOT ENTERED A VALID PHONE NUMBER.
 REMOVE ANY BRACKETS,SPACES OR DASHES AND TRY AGAIN#######',16,1)
END
```